# What is difference between hotkey, shortcut and accelerator key?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

1. What is the difference about them?
2. In Qt, if I have a hotkey for QPushButton, I can make it by "Alt + ?", but if it's for qaction, I can press "?" only

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: If you have two questions, please post them as two different questions. You should not put both in the same "question".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: In this case, it's reasonable to combine them, as the two are definitely related (both address the relation between a key [sequence] and an action). Rule of thumb: If a single answer can be given, it's a single question; if you need two answers, use two questions.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Windows, an **accelerator key** is application global; e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

A **shortcut key** is part of the name of a menu item or button, where it can be underlined, and is available (without modifiers) when that menu item or button is directly available.

From Microsoft:

> A **hot key** is a key combination that the user can press to perform an action quickly. For example, a user can create a hot key that activates a given window and brings it to the top of the z-order.

which seems to indicate that hot keys are system global.

To sum up:

- shortcut key = no modifiers, local in menu or (for button) in window
- accelerator key = typically with modifier, application global
- hot key = apparently system global

I don't know about specific meanings in Qt; for that see the Qt documentation.

Comment: @cheers: can two programs register same hotkey (i.e Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: @TuyenTk: Googling my own quote, it refers to the ["About Hot Key Controls"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN Library. I now see that there are thread-specific hot keys in addition to global hot keys, so ideally someone should use some time researching that and amending the answer... ;-) Anyway, the [documentation of WM_SETHOTKEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "If more than one window has the same hot key, the window that is activated by the hot key is random."

Comment: It make me confused. In the WM_SETHOTKEY document says "These hot keys are unrelated to the hot keys set by RegisterHotKey". The hotkeys I ask is set by RegisterHotKey, which it document says: "RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key". If that "other hot key" registered by other window, can current window register it again?

Comment: @TuyenTk: Apparently the API offers three different kinds of hot keys (global and thread via `WM_SETHOTKEY`, plus those set by `RegisterHotKey`), and all of this is very redundant coming on top of ordinary Windows accelerators and menu shortcuts. I suspect that internally in Microsoft there has been some NIH syndrom, Not Invented Here: we must make our own thingy! Then in the end one cannot really really rely on any of it, not even the established that seems to work, because it can be wantonly removed (as Microsoft did with e.g. HTML+Time, suddenly all apps using that just stopped working).

Comment: `RegisterHotKey` is registered and handled by an application. `WM_SETHOTKEY` is used by `ShellExecuteEx` and works without any extra code in the launched application, `DefWindowProc` does everything. And finally, "access keys" are the underlined controls in a dialog box (Alt+A for Apply etc.).

Comment: How was this completely wrong answer voted correct?

Answer (score 11):

[Alf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169360/594137) is correct for Windows applicability. Your terms you mention (hotkey/shortcut/accelerator) don't sound familiar from a pure Qt point of view.

In Qt you can elect to handle key sequences yourself or you can use Qt's own simplification method. Either way you must remember that Qt itself targets many platforms on which a key combination may or may not make sense. The classic <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> makes sense on a keyboard, but on a mobile device you don't have an <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier or an <kbd>F4</kbd> key. What you really want is a way of specifying a generic *close the application* shortcut. This problem is multiplied because the symbol may be available but the key sequence to reach it might be different on other keyboard layouts. [This section](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues) of the documentation provides a good example.

Qt handles this with [`class QKeySequence`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html). The very clever Qt developers have provided an easy way of defining common user actions and those actions will use key combinations that are default to the target platform. It does this using [`enum QKeySequence::StandardKey`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum) and in the *close the application* example, you could use this like so:

```
QAction exitAction;
exitAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence(QKeySequence::Quit));
```

This is all explained in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#details). There are a two other modifiers ([`shortcutContext()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#shortcutContext-prop) and [`softKeyRole()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#softKeyRole-prop)) which can be applied to QActions which effect their application in more advanced ways.

You are also free to assign your own shortcuts using something like:

```
QAction helpAction(tr("&?"));
helpAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("ALT+?")));
```

The first line applies the (translated) text "?" to the action which will appear as its text on a menu or button. Note that the question mark symbol might not be the right symbol in all languages so the translate method allows a translator to assign a more appropriate symbol if required. The ampersand symbol means the character immediately after will be the short-cut key when the menu is active.

The second line assigns the (translated) shortcut of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> and in this example the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier will be handled by the platform if required. Again, the `tr()` method allows the translator to specify a more appropriate shortcut if available.

---

*In response to teukkam's comment:*

If you mean you simply want your button to be triggerable by a keystroke whether its modified by <kbd>Alt</kbd> or not then you could do something like:

```
QPushButton* yourButton; // assign this pointer yourself
yourButton->setText(tr("&Process"));
yourButton->setShortcut(tr("p"));
```

In this example, the ampersand in `setText()` does the same as the previous example, and the translate function is used in the same way.

The `setShortcut()` method just uses the letter "p" so should work now with or without the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier. A quick skim of the documentation suggests this will work with or without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier as the letters in a key sequence are apparently case-insensitive.

Also, P would be a bad choice as its often assumed to be the *print* command.

A final note if you're defining hard coded short cuts, make sure they work on all your target platforms!

Comment: I think he meant the "?" as a placeholder for the actual letter in question, not a literal question mark.

Comment: thanks for your help..  more what i want to know that : if i have QMenuBar, and it has QMenu("File"), and there is a QAction("&New"), then i want to make it , what i need to do is that clicked "File", then press "N", but if there is QPushButton("&New"), what i shoud do is that : ALT + N,, why need the "ALT" key?  thanks..

Comment: It sounds like you've completely overlooked signals & slots. If you have a QPushButton which needs to trigger a QAction which already exists: connect the button's [`clicked()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal with the action's [`trigger()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#trigger) slot.

Comment: i want to find the difference between it. here is some information about it , [let's see](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10677/45-Day-Series-Codeproject-VC-Forum-Q-A-IV#q410).

Answer (score 6):

In Windows:

## HotKey

**Keyboard key or combination of keys** that execute a command in a given context.

### Shortcut

**Multi-key HotKey** with no menu navigation restrictions nor gui elements required.

#### AccessKey

**Single key HotKey** which command is to activate a **visible command control**
(requires gui element) that is captioned/labeled with the corresponding hotkey letter underscored.

#### Accelerator Keys

**Multi-key HotKey** which command is to activate a **command control** (requires gui element) regardless of its visibility.